# Flink JDBC sink into multiple schemas

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using Flink Jdbc Sink to push data into Postgres tables. The data has to be stored in **different schemas** having the same database connection.

```
DataStream<Book> stream = env.fromSource(...);
```

Each Book record in the stream has details about the schema it has to be stored in.

I tried to parameterize the database schema name in the PreparedStatement, but as expected, that is not allowed by SQL.

```
stream.addSink(JdbcSink.sink(
                    "insert into ?.books (id, title, authors, year) values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                    (statement, book) -> {
                        statement.setString(1, book.schema)
                        statement.setLong(2, book.id);
                        statement.setString(3, book.title);
                        statement.setString(4, book.authors);
                        statement.setInt(5, book.year);
                    },
                    JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
                            .withBatchSize(1000)
                            .withBatchIntervalMs(200)
                            .withMaxRetries(5)
                            .build(),
                    new JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
                            .withUrl("jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:5432/postgresdb")
                            .withDriverName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                            .withUsername("someUser")
                            .withPassword("somePassword")
                            .build()
            ));
```

Is there a workaround for this? Or do I have to explicitly add each schema in a separate sink?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that we have an array of Strings where all the database schemas are listed (can be pre-configured via application properties).

We can filter the stream based on the schema name and create an individual jdbc sink for each schema.

```
String[] schemas = {"schema-1", "schema-2", "schema-3"};

for(int i=0; i<schemas.length; i++){
    stream.filter(x -> x.schema.equals(schemas[i])).addSink(JdbcSink.sink(
                "insert into " + schemas[i] ".books (id, title, authors, year) values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                (statement, book) -> {
                    statement.setLong(1, book.id);
                    statement.setString(2, book.title);
                    statement.setString(3, book.authors);
                    statement.setInt(4, book.year);
                },
                JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
                        .withBatchSize(1000)
                        .withBatchIntervalMs(200)
                        .withMaxRetries(5)
                        .build(),
                new JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
                        .withUrl("jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:5432/postgresdb")
                        .withDriverName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                        .withUsername("someUser")
                        .withPassword("somePassword")
                        .build()
        ));

}
```